# Bootstrap 3: Sticky Footer inside row/col class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I followed the [Sticky Footer example from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) and got it working immediately but is there a way that I can integrate the same sticky footer inside a `.col-md-10`? So that is is **not in full width** but **less wider** than a `.container`?

My [failed attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/KNXs7/2/embedded/result/) so far. Note that I commented `position: absolute` style of `div#footer` because when it is styled, it's looks much worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making the width of the `#footer` the same as a `col-md-10`..

```
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 83.33333333%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**Demo:** http://www.bootply.com/126237

Comment: I was really expecting a "bootstrap"-ish solution but this works find too! thanks a lot!